# Study the uniform continuity of $\sin(\frac{1}{xy})$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, uniform-continuity

Is $f(x,y) = \sin\frac{1}{xy}$ uniformly continuous on $E$, where
$$ E = \lbrace(x,y) | (x-5)^2 + (y - 6)^2 < 1 \rbrace$$ ?

I tried to prove that $f$ is Lipschitz continuous,
$$ \left| \sin \frac{1}{x_1y_1} - \sin \frac{1}{x_2y_2}  \right| = 2\left| \sin \frac{x_2y_2 - x_1y_1}{2x_1y_1x_2y_2}\cos \frac{x_2y_2 + x_1y_1}{2x_1y_1x_2y_2}  \right|  \leq 2 \left| \sin \frac{x_2y_2 - x_1y_1}{2x_1y_1x_2y_2}\right| \leq \left|\frac{x_2y_2 - x_1y_1}{x_1y_1x_2y_2} \right| \leq \left|{x_2y_2 - x_1y_1} \right|  $$ But I don't know what to do next, and whether I'm on the right way to study uniform continuity of $f$  .

Comment: The function $f$ is not defined at all points of $E$. So, what doies it mean to assert that it is uniformly continuous there?